# Remove button readout from NavigationLink with VoiceOver on

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, swiftui-navigationlink

I follow this [guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui) to create navigation programmatically in SwiftUI.

Now the issue is that when VoiceOver is turned on, VoiceOver will read out the `NavigationLink` as `button` although it's completely visually invisible to users.

How do we stop VoiceOver from reading out this `NavigationLink`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingDetailView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) { EmptyView() }

                Button("Tap to show detail") {
                    isShowingDetailView = true
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you are targeting iOS 15 or below, because in iOS 16, you should use [`navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(ispresented:destination:)), which won't have this problem. Even if you are targeting iOS 15, I'd still suggest that you use `@available` to check for iOS 16.

You can use [`accessibilityHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityhidden(_:)) to completely hide an element from the accessibility system.

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: Text("Second View"), 
    isActive: $isShowingDetailView
) { EmptyView() }
    .accessibilityHidden(true)
```